# An example for supporting foreach without implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I am looking at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2007/07/18/ducknotation.aspx)  which explains that `foreach` can be supported without implementing `IEnumerable`. But does not go into the details of the implementation.

I am looking for an example of how to support `foreach` without implementing `IEnumerable`.

Comment: The article seems pretty clear. What don't you understand?

Comment: First, write a class that implements `IEnumerable`, and then get rid of the line that says that you are implementing `IEnumerable` and viola! you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  @Sam I am 's comment, I am able to tweak the code on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) and put together the following, without using IEnumerable or IEnumerator:

```
   //Person Object
   public class Person
   {
        public Person(string fName, string lName)
        {
            this.firstName = fName;
            this.lastName = lName;
        }
    string firstName;
    public string lastName;
   }

   //****Object Collection. 
   //****This class usually needs to implement IEnumerable 
   //****But we are avoiding that here.
   public class People
   {
      private Person[] _people;
      public People(Person[] pArray)
        {
           _people = new Person[pArray.Length];    
           for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
           {
              _people[i] = pArray[i];
           }
         }

    public PeopleEnumSimulator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PeopleEnumSimulator(_people);
    }

    public class PeopleEnumSimulator
    {
        public Person[] _people;

        int position = -1;

        public PeopleEnumSimulator(Person[] list)
        {
            _people = list;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < _people.Length);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            position = -1;
        }

        public Person Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return _people[position];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   


//****Now, Use the Foreach
    Person[] myPeople = new Person[3]
    {
        new Person("John", "Smith"),
        new Person("Jim", "Johnson"),
        new Person("Sue", "Rabon"),
    };
    People peopleList = new People(myPeople);
    foreach (Person p in peopleList)
        Response.Write(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);





//****************************************
//******** A Generic Implementation********
public class People<T>
{
    private T[] _people;
    public People(T[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new T[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }

    public PeopleEnumSimulator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PeopleEnumSimulator(_people);
    }

    public class PeopleEnumSimulator
    {
        public T[] _people;

        int position = -1;

        public PeopleEnumSimulator(T[] list)
        {
            _people = list;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < _people.Length);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            position = -1;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return _people[position];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

       // use the foreach
       //For Type Person
            People<Person> peopleList = new People<Person>(myPeople);

            foreach (Person p in peopleList)
                Response.Write(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);

            //break
            Response.Write(" </br></br></br>       ");

            //For Type Int
            int[] n3 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

            People<int> intList = new People<int>(n3);

            foreach (int p in intList)
                Response.Write(p);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a class that doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, or any interfaces at all:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
    }
}
```

You can `foreach` it like so:

```
foreach (int n in new Foo())
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

And this will print:

> 1
>   2

Comment: +1. Indeed you can also implement `IEnumerator`'s methods by hand and *not derive* from `IEnumerator`... but sample will be much longer. `foreach` is example of [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (along with new `dynamic`) in C#.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah, I did this simply because it was quite a lot shorter than such a solution would be, as it would mean I couldn't use an iterator block.