# How does the List<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action) method actually work?

Tags: c#, list, methods, foreach

I've looked at the documentation of the List.ForEach(Action action) method but it only says what it does, not how it does it. I know it takes an action and performs that action on all of the elements of the list. But what is the actual code that it uses to accomplish this? Is there a way I could make my own ForEach method that works the same way as the lists ForEach method?

I have had times in the past where I want to condense my ForEach loops and this looks like it would work well in some of those circumstances, especially when I'm using custom classes.

Comment: A normal `foreach` statement takes an `IEnumerable` (or the generic version if it's a generic collection) and calls `GetEnumerator` on it, returning an `IEnumerator` (perhaps `of T`). Then it uses the enumerator to walk through the collection. Te `List<T>.ForEach` method is an extension method that walks the list (using a simple `foreach`)  and calls the given `Action<T>` on each member of the list. It is trivial to wrote (simply write an extension method on the list class that does what I described. There's no magic there

Comment: @Flydog57 C# also supports using `foreach` with _any object_ that has a `GetEnumerator()` method - types don't need to implement `IEnumerable` anymore. This was done to support value-type collections without boxing to an interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486382/an-example-for-supporting-foreach-without-implementing-ienumerable

Comment: @dai: And C# also special-cases non-generic collections, providing a way to do type-safe enumeration even though the non-generic `IEnumerator` methods only work with `object`s. That was implemented back in the v1.0 and v1.1 days (before generics were introduced in v2.0) so that programmers didn't have to sprinkle casts into `foreach` loops

Comment: @Flydog57 Uhhh, not to the same extent as you're suggesting. The `foreach` statement still performs an unsafe cast in C# 7, 8, and I think 9 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll extract if from the c# source code, which is [published online on a dedicated site at MS](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5,references) and [also on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) - useful resources to bookmark:

```
 public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
        if( action == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        int version = _version;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
            if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5) {
                break;
            }
            action(_items[i]);
        }

        if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }
```

Mostly it's just fluff for version checking and throwing, the core part is a for loop that takes the method you provided and invokes it passing in every list item in turn:

```
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
            action(_items[i]);
        }

    }
```

You absolutely can write it yourself in your own classes, and it would look just like that. This is the .NET framework version - the core version won't be vastly different

Note that it's not a huge char saving:

```
foreach(var v in vList) myMethod(v);
vList.ForEach(myMethod);

foreach(var v in vList)
  if(v.X > 10)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Y);

vList.ForEach(v => {
  if(v.X > 10)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Y);
});
```

And foreach remains fairly readable for most as it gets longer, whereas when you start getting into multi line lambda they can end up a bit more messy looking and not significantly more condensed